# Ubuntu Gnome: No such file or directory [remove steam]

Tags: dependencies, uninstall, directory, steam, cleanup

The intention was to remove **steam**

1. 1st: `sudo apt-get remove steam` [if steam was installed via terminal]
2. 2nd: `rm -rf ~/.local/share/Steam && rm -rf ~/.steam` [remove steam
   dependencies]

But I installed steam via Lutris once and Ubuntu Software and **uninstalled** it via Lutris and Ubuntu Software
[image]
[image]

However after searching for any steam files in the terminal, I found the following [many files] but I  have pointed out to one file for this investigation and analysis.

1. `mlocate steam`

[image]

There are endless steam packages and files, including this **steam.desktop** file

However If you try to navigate to it, you get the following:

```
cd /usr/share/applications
```

***/usr/share/applications$*** `ls`

I cannot find the steam.desktop file??
[image]

I also tried to open a different file and you get the following.

```
xdg-open /usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/steam.png
```

**No such file or directory**

Can someone please provide clarity as to why these files are visible but cannot be navigated to or opened.

Answer (score 2):

`mlocate` is a tool that reads its findings from one or more databases created or refreshed by the command:

```bsh
sudo updatedb
```

Update the database and try again.

Or use `find`:

```bsh
sudo find / -iname steam
```

But this can take a while, when your drive(s) are bigger.

Comment: please note that your suggestion worked #Thank_You. 

I verified the results by running the following: `mlocate steam | grep -i desktop`
and there was nothing.